# Как добавить css класс .active, а потом через несколько секунд удалить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы

Например если есть в массиве совпадения с data-id , тогда блок подсвечивается на две секунды,
 а через две секунды класс удаляется с эффектом как на сайте на котором мы сейчас( на странице где есть ваши ответы на вопросы ).

Я сделал подсветку блоков, если есть совпадения в массиве.

Подскажите как сделать такой эффект как на сайте на котором мы сейчас и автоматическое удаление подсветки?

Или какие-то другие ваши идеи как это можно сделать.

```js
var arr = ["1", "2", "4", "7", "9"];
if (arr) {

  arr.forEach(function(item, cook) {
    $('.blok[data-id="' + item + '"]').addClass('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.blok {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  color: #555;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.blok:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#names {
  color: #0D6AF3;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.active {
  background-color: #FF0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blok" data-id="1">
  <div class="names">Блок 1</div>
</div>


<div class="blok" data-id="3">
  <div class="names">Блок 2</div>
</div>



<div class="blok" data-id="4">
  <div class="names">Блок 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что вам подойдет специальный плагин для анимации, который называется `jquery-color-master`.

Берете подключаете плагин - [Страница плагина jquery-color](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/)

и замените свой код js на этот:

```
var arr = ["1", "2", "4", "7", "9"];

if (arr) {    
  arr.forEach(function(item, cook) {
    $('.blok[data-id="' + item + '"]').css('background-color', '#FF0').animate({
      "background-color": 'transparent'
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо хороший плагин.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью CSS3 @keyframes, затем по истечении задержки setTimeout удалить класс.

```js
var arr = ["1", "2", "4", "7", "9"];
if (arr) {

  arr.forEach(function(item, cook) {
    $('.blok[data-id="' + item + '"]').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {  $('.blok[data-id="' + item + '"]').removeClass('active'); }, 3000)

  });
}
```

```css
.blok {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  color: #555;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.blok:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#names {
  color: #0D6AF3;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
   @-webkit-keyframes pulse  {
0% {background-color: #F8E71C;} 
100% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
   }
   
  @keyframes pulse  {
   0% {background-color: #F8E71C;} 
   100% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
  }
 
 .active {
border: 1px solid #000;
animation: pulse 3s 0;
-webkit-animation: pulse 3s 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blok" data-id="1">
  <div class="names">Блок 1</div>
</div>


<div class="blok" data-id="3">
  <div class="names">Блок 2</div>
</div>



<div class="blok" data-id="4">
  <div class="names">Блок 3</div>
</div>
```